# what is the fix for>> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in /home/uavpilot/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 615

Tags: magento-1.9

I am getting the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in /home/uavpilot/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 615

The confusing part, is that there is no -> ? <-  on line 615.
 - The UAVpilot in the path is my website folder on the host server, with magento installed at the root of public_html. 
 - I verified prior to install that the server is able to run all of the
   patches and associated technologies for Magento.

Answer (score 1):

Without source code access it will be very hard to diagnose this problem.

There are some things to check:

- Syntax errors in the referenced file.
- Does it work if PHP short tags is enabled ? If it does it may be that your theme is using them and needs to be fixed
- use default Magento theme again this can help verify if your theme is the source of the fault
- disable custom third party modules perhaps someones rewrote something into local to replace some core functionality.

Failing those review your Apache / php error logs sometimes they give more detail to help you isolate where the problem is coming from.